# WIX: How can I uninstall a previous MSI built using a VS *.vdproj

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using WIX to create a new installer for an existing product. The installer is very simple - just drops a few dll's into a specified folder on disk.

In the field, my users already have that folder with old dll's in them (since they installed the old MSI - created using a *.vdproj project in VS).

My problem is that after I install the WIX, I have both the old MSI and the new Wix MSI appear in Add/Remove. Expected (? since these 2 are two different kind of MSI's?). I need some kind of an upgrade mechanism - so I was wondering if I can call the old MSI uninstaller from within the WIX one. Or alternately somehow take care of the old Add/Remove entry (a registry hack perhaps?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the old install and the new install are installed using the same context ( per-user -> per-user or per-machine -> per-machine )  you can use a MajorUpgrade rule to find the old version and get rid of it.  You can do this by syncing up the UpgradeCode property and using a higher ProductVersion or you can do it by authoring a second Upgrade rule using the legacy UpgradeCode GUID.

If the old install was per-user and you want the new install to be per-machine you are out of luck.  This isn't supported by MSI.   Typically I only support per-machine installs and hardcode the ALLUSERS property and remove the CustomerInformation dialog from the installer UI experience.   This is not the default experience for VDPROJ based installers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll research how to do the MajorUpgrade approach, since WIX is new to me.

Comment: Christopher, can you elaborate on this: "You can do this by syncing up the UpgradeCode property and using a higher ProductVersion or you can do it by authoring a second Upgrade rule using the legacy UpgradeCode GUID"? Does this approach take into account that old MSI is not WIX?

Comment: Oh .. when you say "sync the UpgradeCode" you mean make the new Wix UpgradeCode match the old one?

Comment: Yes. Assuming well behaving MSI's,  Windows Installer doesn't really care what tool authored the MSI when doing a Major Upgrade.  Minor Upgrades would be very difficult as even subtle changes to tables  / primary keys can cause problems.