# My last patch went out with the wrong UpgradeCode. How can I fix this in a subsequent patch?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, patch

## Premise

I am using WiX Toolset 3.5.

I have successfully released several patches for my product that use the same UpgradeCode and ProductCode. However, the most recent two patches incorrectly went out with a different UpgradeCode. These patches installed successfully, but my latest patch refuses to install.

Here is my release history since the last MSI release:

1. Installer (10.0.20935.0) with UpgradeCode A.
2. Patch (10.0.21069.0) with UpgradeCode A.
3. Patch (10.0.21188.0) with UpgradeCode A.
4. Patch (10.0.21334.0) with UpgradeCode A.
5. Patch (10.0.21671.0) with UpgradeCode A.
6. Patch (10.1.0.264) with **UpgradeCode B**.
7. Patch (10.1.0.21682) with **UpgradeCode C**.
8. Patch (10.2.0.0), the latest patch, fails regardless of whether I use UpgradeCode A, B or C.

Below is the error message that appears when I try to install patch 10.2.0.0:

> The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch.

The user is not allowed to install the patch.

---

## Question

I need to release a patch that

- installs successfully on production (10.1.0.21682).
- allows me to continue releasing patches in the future.

How do I achieve this?

---

## What have I tried?

I have tried the following, with no success:

- Changing the UpgradeCode to A, i.e. the one from 10.0.21671.0 and earlier.
- Changing the UpgradeCode to B, i.e. the one from 10.1.0.264.
- Changing the UpgradeCode to C, i.e. the one from 10.1.0.21682.
- Changing the ProductCode.
- Creating a patch straight from 10.0.21671.0 to 10.2.0.0 (though of course in production it will be run on 10.1.0.21682).

All of the above scenarios result in the same error message (given in the premise). I have also found the following question on StackOverflow:

- [WIX: When upgrading, what to do when there are 2 different UpgradeCodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818362/)

This led to me adding `OnlyDetect="no"` to the `<UpgradeVersion>` element of a new `<Upgrade>` element in my product's .wxs file:

```
<Upgrade Id="UpgradeCode C">
  <UpgradeVersion Property="OLD_PRODUCT_FOUND"
                  IncludeMaximum="yes"
                  Maximum="10.2.0.0"
                  MigrateFeatures="yes"
                  OnlyDetect="no" />
</Upgrade>
```

However, this had the exact same outcome as before.

---

## Sample Code

I have created a small project that I use to replicate my scenario.

Below is the .wxs file for version 10.2.0.0 of the product from my test project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="{8CB0CC73-82B1-495E-B768-D1C38372678A}"
        Name="Sample Application"
        Language="1033"
        Version="10.2.0.0"
        Manufacturer="Sample Corporation"
        UpgradeCode="{7E72848F-FC99-4737-87DE-91C738B7C5EE}">

        <Package Description="Installs a file that will be patched."
            Comments="This Product does not install any executables"
            InstallerVersion="200"
            Compressed="yes" />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <FeatureRef Id="SampleProductFeature"/>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Feature Id="SampleProductFeature" Title="Sample Product Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="Sample.txt" />
        </Feature>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SampleProductFolder">
            <Component Id="Sample.txt" Guid="{d738b2a9-0dbc-4381-9efd-5801723b1569}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="Sample.txt" Name="Sample.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\Sample.txt" />             
            </Component>    
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="SampleProductFolder" Name="Patch Sample Directory">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Below is the .wxs file for the patch to version 10.2.0.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch 
        AllowRemoval="no"
        Manufacturer="Sample Corp" 
        MoreInfoURL="http://www.dynamocorp.com/"
        DisplayName="Sample Patch" 
        Description="Small Update Patch" 
        Classification="Update"
        OptimizedInstallMode="yes">

        <Media Id="8000" Cabinet="RTM.cab" CompressionLevel="none">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM">            
            </PatchBaseline>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="SamplePatchFamily"/>    
    </Patch>

    <Fragment>    
        <PatchFamily Id='SamplePatchFamily' Version='10.2.0.0' Supersede='no'>
        </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, it turns out, is as simple as disabling validation of the UpgradeCode for the newest patch. This can be done by setting the `UpgradeCode` attribute on the `Validate` to "no".

```
<Media Id="8000" Cabinet="RTM.cab" CompressionLevel="none">
    <PatchBaseline Id="RTM">
        <Validate UpgradeCode="no" />
    </PatchBaseline>
</Media>
```

This 10.2.0.0 patch, which introduces a new UpgradeCode, runs successfully on top of 10.1.0.21682, and I was able to successfully execute three subsequent patches. (These patches have UpgradeCode validation enabled and share the same UpgradeCode as 10.2.0.0.)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't change the ProductCode. If you have been building MSI files that changed the UpgradeCode then maybe more critical items are changing.  You built a patch that targets a product with a specific ProductCode and PackageCode (based on the MSI files you created) and that's what it wants.

Most importantly, I'd check that patch 7 with UpgradeCode C did not change the installed product's ProductCode or PackageCode because that's the patch that produced the problem, and if your new patch 8 cannot find a product to patch it's the ProductCode and PackageCode it'll be looking for. That's what the error is saying - the ProductCode (or PackageCode) targeted by this patch is not installed. In other words I doubt very much that the UpgradeCode matters in that error message, and that linked article about upgrading more than one product with a major upgrade has no bearing on a patching issue like this unless you are worried about major upgrades, in which case you just list all the UpgradeCodes that need upgrading, and so it's not an issue.

Comment: In my test project, the only things that change between patches are the UpgradeCode and the Version. This is also true for patch 7 which introduced the problem.